# Manipulating PDF hyperlink after creation

Tags: perl, pdf, hyperlink

I am creating a PDF document with Google Slides containing placeholder for hyperlinks. On a local machine, I want to replace those placeholder with local hyperlinks.

To do this I am using a perl search and replace function:

```
perl -i~ -0777 -pe 's/\/URI\s*\/URI\s*\(\#Tools_notepad\)/\/Launch\/F(C:\/\/Program Files (x86)\/\/Notepad\+\+\/\/notepad\+\+\.exe)/g' link_problem.pdf
```

After that, I want to cut off pages using pdftk and get a java NullPointer:

```
$ pdftk link_problem.pdf cat 1 output link_problem_pdftked.pdf

Error: Unexpected Exception in open_reader()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at 0x0059a84e (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\Throwable.java)
at 0x0059ad42 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\Throwable.java)
at 0x0059adf3 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\Throwable.java)
at 0x005e9bed (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\Exception.java)
at 0x005ba4bd (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\RuntimeException.java)
at 0x005b91ad (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\NullPointerException.java)
at 0x00597242 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\prims.cc)
at 0x004e1e81 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\java_lib.jar)
at 0x004e04c6 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\java_lib.jar)
at 0x004df3e2 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\java_lib.jar)
at 0x004df38a (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\java_lib.jar)
at 0x0041a16a (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\pdftk.cc)
at 0x0041af94 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\pdftk.cc)
at 0x0041d187 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\pdftk.cc)
at 0x00421e89 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\pdftk.cc)
at 0x0042298a (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\pdftk.cc)
at 0x0058ed52 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\crt1.c)
at 0x0058ede4 (C:\Users\ngrebner\Documents\OSOCC-Structure\04 Operations\tmp\crt1.c)
at 0x770c3366 (Unknown Source)
at 0x776a98fe (Unknown Source)
at 0x776a98d1 (Unknown Source)
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
link_problem.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Using QPDF I get a feeling for the problem:

```
$ qpdf --check link_problem.pdf
WARNING: link_problem.pdf: file is damaged
WARNING: link_problem.pdf (file position 112664): xref not found
WARNING: link_problem.pdf: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table
operation for Dictionary object attempted on object of wrong type
```

Now, obviously by manipulating the PDF file with Perl, I change a xref reference and pdftk cannot handle that. Just to mention: PDF readers are working fine with the file now.

One solution would be to use pdftk first and perl afterwards, but this results in other problems in my work flow.

Here is a link to my minimum example PDF file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwvpX97bvnDuT1FhTGFxbWlueHc

Does anyone have an idea how I could split the file after using my perl command?